# Calculate mean of Values per Minute by Pivot Table By date and Station in R

Tags: r, pivot-table

thanks for your time, could you please help me with this data table?

I have a dataset like that:

| Station | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| St1 | 22/01/2021 11:25:45 | 5,703 |
| St1 | 22/01/2021 11:25:46 | 4,603 |
| St1 | 22/01/2021 11:25:47 | 3,703 |
| St2 | 22/01/2021 11:25:45 | 5,803 |
| St2 | 22/01/2021 11:25:46 | 5,223 |
| St3 | 22/01/2021 11:25:45 | 6,333 |
| St3 | 22/01/2021 11:25:46 | 3,733 |

I'd like to obtain a sort of pivotable like that:

| Date | St1 | St2 | St3. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/01/2021 11:25 | MeanValueOfMinute(11:25) | MeanValueOfMinute(11:25) | MeanValueOfMinute(11:25) |
| 22/01/2021 11:26 | MeanValueOfMinute(11:26) | MeanValueOfMinute(11:26) | MeanValueOfMinute(11:26) |

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ceiling_date` from `lubridate` to round date-time values and cast the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = ceiling_date(dmy_hms(Date), 'min'), 
         Value = parse_number(Value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Station, values_from = Value, values_fn = mean)

#  Date                  St1   St2   St3
#  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2021-01-22 11:26:00 4670.  5513  5033
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Station = c("St1", "St1", "St1", "St2", "St2", 
"St3", "St3"), Date = c("22/01/2021 11:25:45", "22/01/2021 11:25:46", 
"22/01/2021 11:25:47", "22/01/2021 11:25:45", "22/01/2021 11:25:46", 
"22/01/2021 11:25:45", "22/01/2021 11:25:46"), Value = c("5,703", 
"4,603", "3,703", "5,803", "5,223", "6,333", "3,733")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```